# Braintree Create Plan using API

Tags: php, braintree

Is there any way to create Plan using php API? In the documentation, its given that one needs to manually create plan from the account but i want to create Plan dynamically from the system.

Comment: I just posted an up-to-date answer. Can you check it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Braintree recurring billing docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/recurring-billing/plans):

> Plans are created in the Control Panel. You cannot create or update them through the API.

Comment: Wow, this is a real disadvantage of the API... terrible for us developers who want to handle this for the customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create the plans using API
you will have to manually create them and set the parameters

you can use discount codes to alter the existing plans without creating a new one

I am pretty sure that will fulfill almost every requirement for creating a new plan

Comment: does the end user see these discounts?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Braintree docs](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/recurring-billing/plans), it's now possible to create plans via the API:

```
gateway.plan.create({
  name: "the_name",
  billingFrequency: "the_billing_frequency",
  currencyIsoCode: "the_currency_iso_code",
  price: "the_price"
}).then(result => { });
```

> Before creating subscriptions, you must create a plan. You can also retrieve existing plans via the API. A plan is a template for your subscriptions: when you create a plan, it will be used to populate the following attributes when a new subscription is created:
>
> - plan name
> - description
> - trial period
> - billing day of month
> - number of billing cycles
> - amount
> - currency
> - billing cycle